# What is this bash parameter expansion syntax?

Tags: bash, parameter-expansion

I've never seen this `+x}` syntax before and I can't find docs about it. What does it do?

```sh
if [[ -z "${EMPLOYEE_CLUSTER+x}" ]]; then
  export EMPLOYEE_CLUSTER=shared
fi
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the variable `EMPLOYEE_CLUSTER` is defined (even to an empty string), the expansion expands to `x`.  Since `x` is not an empty string, the `[[` test will evaluate to true.  If the variable is not defined, the expansion expands to nothing, and the test evaluates to false.  Note that the presence of a colon in `${EMPLOYEE_CLUSTER:+x}` changes the expansion; the variable must be set and non-empty to get the `x` output.

It is a slightly unusual usage, but it is hard to do better in a test like that where an empty value is permissible but the variable must be set.  The notation is more commonly used to conditionally pass values to a command.  For example:

```
mythical-creature ${UNICORN:+"-u"} ${UNICORN}
```

This will pass the `-u` option to `mythical-creature` if `$UNICORN` is defined and non-empty — as well as the value stored in `$UNICORN`.  If `$UNICORN` is not defined and non-empty, no arguments are passed to the command.

See [Shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) in the Bash manual — it is the fourth documented notation in this section.